# How to force babel to ignore syntax but not the file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, next.js

I am trying to use babel to copy my files to a lib folder (so later on I use them as shared components for other projects). I don't want babel to transpile the React code since I will do it in my main projects. But I do want babel to change absolute paths to relative paths while copying the files. Nothing else.

All I want from babel so to convert:

```
import Temp from 'components/Temp';
```

To

```
import Temp from './src/components/Temp';
```

My project doesn't have any Webpack, don't need that actually. It only has Storybook and bunch of components.

this is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "comments": true,
  "compact": false,
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["."],
        "alias": {
          "components": "./src/components",
          "pages": "./src/pages",
          "shared": "./src/shared",
          "mocks": "./src/mocks"
        },
        "cwd": "babelrc"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

this is my package.json build script:

```
    "build": "babel src --out-dir lib --ignore README.md,src/.next,**/*.stories.js --copy-files",
```

While the copy for some files happen at some point it stops and because of different errors like  this syntax errors:

```
 "Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled"
```

I want babel to ignore anything that it sees in the files and just change the import file addresses. I don't want to include plugins like "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties". There are JSX and lots of other stuff in each file and I don't want babel to touch them.

Is the a way to force babel to close its eyes on Syntax errors and just use the "module-resolver" plugin?

My babel version is 7

Thanks!

Comment: why would your React files contain absolute paths to begin with? This should be just a simple file copy rather than babel?

Comment: What do you mean by doing imports with absolute paths?  Are you aliasing your module locations with webpack?

Comment: All I want babel to do is to convert 

this:
import Temp from 'components/Temp'

to this:
import './src/components/Temp"

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: If you have this non-standard file structure, you need to do it yourself. It just a simple matter of passing your file to a filter and perform search and replace (before gone into Babel). And this is why most front-end setup rarely just use babel and use webpack or rollup this kind of tools to help perform extra task.

Comment: Agagin though: why? ES module imports are already relative to the module itself, why would you have to change _anything_ when you copy the files? You have one authoritative source tree, and then you have your dist etc. dirs for bundled/packed code. Why would you need to duplicate the regular code, especially if that duplication now needs to point to a different dir just for its own imports to work? E.g: what are you _actually_ doing that made you decide this was a good solution? Because this is almost certainly an XY problem...

Comment: Babel cannot transform a file if it cannot parse the file, so there is no way to transform imports without enabling all the plugins needed to parse the file.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well here is the scenario:

I have 3 NextJS apps, and 2 different libraries as Shared libraries (npm packages) to be shared between these 3 apps. with only babel config if I apply all the presets everything works great right now, no Webpack needed. 
The only reason Im trying to find a new solution is I want to be able to support next/dynamic in those external libraries so I can lazy load components that are NOT accessible in the nextJS apps. Imagine a modal that opens up in one of the libraries, I want that modal to lazy load and the nextJS apps don't know about it.